# My program cannot read and display contents in a file

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles, file-handling

I have an assignment that I need to create a program to read (in binary mode) a file and then display them out on the screen. I run it in the command line mode. Here is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXWORD 130
typedef struct Node node;
struct Node
{
    int stt;
    char name[50];
    char phonenumber[20];
    char email[50];
};
int checktoread(FILE *datain)
{
    return (datain == NULL);
}
int readfile(FILE *datain, node *item)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(fread(&item[i], sizeof(node), 1, datain)>0)
    {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
void display(node *item, int max)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < max; i++)
    {
        printf("%-3d%-30s%-20s%-30s\n", item[i].stt, item[i].name, item[i].phonenumber, item[i].email);
    }
}

int main(int argv, char *argc[])
{
    if (argv != 2)
    {
        printf("Wrong syntax\nCorrect Syntax: readfile <source file>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE *fp = fopen(argc[1], "rb");
    if(checktoread(fp))
    {
        printf("The source file is unable to be opened\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    node *person = (node*) malloc(30*sizeof(person));
    int maxline = readfile(fp, person);
    printf("%d\n", maxline);
    display(person, maxline);
    fclose(fp);
    free(person);
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is this file do not return or display anything. There is no syntax error here, I confirm. I don't know where I get wrong. Actually, I think it get wrong in the step that convert data from a file into an array.

The file starts like this

```
            0  1  2  3   4  5  6  7   8  9  A  B   C  D  E  F
0000:0000  01 00 00 00  4A 6F 65 79  4D 61 74 68  65 6C 00 00
0000:0010  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
0000:0020  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
0000:0030  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
0000:0040  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
0000:0050  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
0000:0060  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  30 33 38 35  37 38 38 30
0000:0070  36 30 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  6A 6F 65 79
0000:0080  6D 61 74 68  65 6C 40 67  6D 61 69 6C  2E 63 6F 6D
0000:0090  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
0000:00A0  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
0000:00B0  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
0000:00C0  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
0000:00D0  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
0000:00E0  02 00 00 00  53 63 6F 74  74 79 4A 61  63 6B 00 00
0000:00F0  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
```

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(person))` needs to be `malloc(sizeof(*person)*max)`. Also, suggest you run your program in a debugger and step thru the code line by line examining variables as you go.

Comment: Please show a (short) example of the input file. The question says "binary mode" but you are counting text lines, and then reading a fixed length.

Comment: @WeatherVane Im so sorry that I do not contain the binary file I use. I have edited it

Comment: Please copy/paste it as text (or a text dump), into the question.

Comment: @kaylum I have run as you suggested but it didn't work. Maybe the problem is in another place

Comment: @WeatherVane I can't because the file is in binary mode, you can download it in the link I gave you, please

Comment: Sorry, that is not how this site [works](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). But if the file is binary, why are you using `fgets` to find the number of records?

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh I see that problem, how can I get the number of items in that binary files?

Comment: @Scotty That may not be your only problem but it certainly is a very big problem.

Comment: I'm new in this website, therefore I do not know how to post a text in binary in this file. Can you edit it?

Comment: To get the number of items divide the file size by the item size (assuming it contains all the same fixed sized items). But again, really encourage you to use a debugger. Or even basic debug print statements. For example, why haven't you even checked the value of `max`?

Comment: As there are no newlines in the formatted file (except by chance data) then `fgets` isn't going to work.

Comment: I see that problem here to get the ``max`` value. so how do I take the ``max`` value here?

Comment: @kaylum I have used my debugger, however I don't know why the debugger always check my source file as empty, so it exits the program immediately after displaying the message. However, it does not even shows the message in reality

Comment: If you are having trouble starting your debugger then would advise you to post a new question to get that sorted out. Having a functioning debugger is critical. But you are not passing the source file to the debugger are you? You need to give it the executable file.

Comment: BTW please no not use `max` which is a macro in stdlib, pick another name. You can find its value by either (a) find the file size and divide by `struct` size or (b) read the file twice but don't store anything first time.

Comment: @kaylum In the case I need to debug, I have to edit my code in order to I have source file to read. Otherwise It will not run even the first step which checks the number of argument

Comment: It sounds like you are running it incorrectly. There is absolutely no reason the code needs to be edited just to run it in the debugger. As I said, post a new question for that as it is a seperate issue. But in the mean time you can still use good old debug `printf` statements.

Comment: The problem here is that it return the file I read is NULL when I debug it. I don't know why